# What is the "box model?"

Tags: css

During a recent interview for a front-end developer position I was asked what the box model was. I thought the interviewer was referring to testing (i.e. white box testing, black box testing). I was wrong.

What is the box model, in reference to front-end development?

Comment: Really, google for "box model front-end"...

Answer (score 7):

Here's a great [tutorial on CSS box model](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/) by BrainJar.com

Google has [quite a few](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+box+model) other links as well.

Comment: +1 The BrainJar article is an awesome and really helpful read.

Answer (score 1):

Once they've asked you at the interview about CSS Box model, they didn't asked only for definition, but they rather expected that you had working experience with applying knowledge about Box Model and Layout techniques.
I strongly recommend learning about Box Model from W3 CSS2 spec website, but also practicing CSS and table-less design, as well as checking best practices for websites Layout techniques
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with web application development and css.
See this:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

K

Answer (score 0):

The interviewer was likely refering to the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Answer (score 0):

By "box model", your interviewer was probably referring to the CSS Box Model. The CSS box model is a system of borders, margins, and paddings (and more recently , outlines) that surround block level objects and help the browser determine how to display them. Pick up a good CSS book for more info.